# How to add basic auth for some links when we have an authentication system in place

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-security, basic-authentication, cloudfoundry-uaa

We are using UAA for authentication as of now. However, for a couple of links (RestController links), I need to add basic authentication with username and password. I'm able to add only 1. Not able to add UAA and basic auth both. Any help would be appreceated.

Here is the webconfig code with UAA

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to have multiple security configurations, i.e. extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter multiple times. That way you can have different configurations (login methods etc, your basic auth), for different paths.

See the official documentation for code examples: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#multiple-httpsecurity